# why does navigation to /logout not work in sails-permissions?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I cannot logout of my sailsJS app using sails-permissions.  I have tried both a GET and a POST to /logout and to /auth/logout, but I still have an active user session.  What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following line to your `config/routes.js` file?

`'get /logout': 'AuthController.logout'`